# The Most Efficient Implementation of UniqueQueue and UniqueReplacementQueue Collections in .NET

Tags: c#, collections, performance, queue, unique

What is the most efficient (in terms of speed) implementation of UniqueQueue and UniqueReplacementQueue collections in .NET considering the fact that the speed of Enqueue and Dequeue operations is equally important.

UniqueQueue is a queue where duplicates are not possible. So if I push an element to the queue it is added in only case it doesn't already exist in the queue.

UniqueReplacementQueue is a queue where duplicates are not possible either. The difference is that if I push an element which already exists in the queue, it replaces the existing element at the same position. It makes sense for reference types.

My current implementation of UniqueQueue and UniqueReplacementQueue:

```
sealed class UniqueQueue<T> : IQueue<T>
{
    readonly LinkedList<T> list;
    readonly IDictionary<T, int> dictionary;

    public UniqueQueue(LinkedList<T> list, IDictionary<T, int> dictionary)
    {
        this.list = list;
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get { return list.Count; }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The queue is empty");
        }

        var element = list.First.Value;
        dictionary.Remove(element);
        list.RemoveFirst();

        return element;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T element)
    {
        dictionary[element] = 0;

        if (dictionary.Count > list.Count)
        {
            list.AddLast(element);
        }
    }
}

sealed class UniqueReplacementQueue<T> : IQueue<T>
{
    readonly LinkedList<T> list;
    readonly IDictionary<T, T> dictionary;

    public UniqueReplacementQueue(LinkedList<T> list, IDictionary<T, T> dictionary)
    {
        this.list = list;
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get { return list.Count; }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The queue is empty");
        }

        var element = dictionary[list.First.Value];
        dictionary.Remove(element);
        list.RemoveFirst();

        return element;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T element)
    {
        dictionary[element] = element;

        if (dictionary.Count > list.Count)
        {
            list.AddLast(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added my current implementation of UniqueQueue and UniqueReplacementQueue classes.

Comment: Most Efficient for what? There are usually multiple, competing measures by which you can compare different implementations of `X` - without defining which measure(s) you're attempting to (min|max)imize, how can we determine which is the most efficient?

Comment: Fair point. Updated the question: "... (in terms of speed) ... considering the fact that the speed of Enqueue and Dequeue operations is equally important ..."

Answer (score 15):

This is pretty old, but how about a class that has an internal HashSet, and Queue. A custom method for Enqueue firsts tries to add it to the hashset. if the HashSet.Add call returns false, we do not enqueue it. HashSet.Add() is an O(1) operation if the set is of a size large enough to hold all elements.

The only drawback to this is memory usage if this is a concern for you. Here is an implementation:

```
public class UniqueQueue<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    private HashSet<T> hashSet;
    private Queue<T> queue;


    public UniqueQueue() {
        hashSet = new HashSet<T>();
        queue = new Queue<T>();
    }


    public int Count {
        get {
            return hashSet.Count;
        }
    }

    public void Clear() {
        hashSet.Clear();
        queue.Clear();
    }


    public bool Contains(T item) {
        return hashSet.Contains(item);
    }


    public void Enqueue(T item) {
        if (hashSet.Add(item)) {
            queue.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue() {
        T item = queue.Dequeue();
        hashSet.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }


    public T Peek() {
        return queue.Peek();
    }


    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return queue.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return queue.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The HashSet is used whenever it can because it is typically faster. This could be nicer if the maintainers of .NET marked these methods as virtual, but alas here we are.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
//the UniqueQueueItem has the key in itself,
//and implements the IUniqueQueueItemable to copy the other values.
//For example:
class TestUniqueQueueItem : IUniqueQueueItemable<TestUniqueQueueItem>
{
    //Key
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }

    //To copy the other values.
    public void CopyWith(TestUniqueQueueItem item)
    {
        this.Name = item.Name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Id == ((TestUniqueQueueItem)obj).Id;
    }
}

internal interface IUniqueQueueItemable<in T>
{
    void CopyWith(T item);
}

class UniqueQueue<T> where T: IUniqueQueueItemable<T>
{
    private readonly bool _isReplacementQueue;
    private readonly Queue<T> _queue;
    private readonly Dictionary<T, T> _dictionary;

    public UniqueQueue(): this(false)
    {
    }

    public UniqueQueue(bool isReplacementQueue)
    {
        _isReplacementQueue = isReplacementQueue;
        _queue = new Queue<T>();
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<T, T>();
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        if(!_dictionary.Keys.Contains(item))
        {
            _dictionary.Add(item, item);
           _queue.Enqueue(item);
        }
        else
        {
            if(_isReplacementQueue)
            {
                //it will return the existedItem, which is the same key with the item 
                //but has different values with it.
                var existedItem = _dictionary[item];

                //copy the item to the existedItem. 
                existedItem.CopyWith(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        var item = _queue.Dequeue();
        _dictionary.Remove(item);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: `var existingItem = dictionary[item]; existingItem.CopyWith(item);` vs `dictionary[item] = item;`. I can't see difference in performance. Anyway we have to do dictionary lookup. All assignments and comparisons are insignificant in this case.

Comment: The selection of the dictionary is that the complexity is ideally O(1), and the Queue<T> wrapper would relatively be high performance. If you feel it isn't enough to satisfy, I think you are difficult to find the solution as you expect. Good luck to you!

Comment: This is using the dictionary just to store keys. Dictionaries are implemented as a hash table. So it is doing the same as the other method which uses hashset. It just wastes a bit of memory and time storing (key,value) pairs